# AWS CLI, pass output of previous command as input for another?

Tags: linux, nat, aws

I would like to create a Bash script that will start and stop specific resources in AWS. The problem I have is I would like to create a resource the requires the a specific resource ID that was created by the previous command. The goal is to be able to run a single script to start the resources instead of editing.

For example creating a NAT gateway then appending the ID of the NAT-gateway created to a route table command:

```
$ aws ec2 create-nat-gateway
```

Sample output:

```
"NatGatewayId": "nat-1111111"

$ aws ec2 replace-route --route-table-id rtb-000000000 \
  --destination-cidr-block 0.0.0.0/0 --nat-gateway-id "***nat-id-output***"
```

Comment: Have a look at ansible

Answer (score 1):

```
O=$(aws ec2 create-nat-gateway | perl -pe 's/.*: //g');
while true ; do
    C=$(aws ect describe-nat-gateways --nat-gateway-ids "$O" | grep -c available || true);
    if [ $C -gt 0 ] ; then
        break;
    fi
    sleep 3;
done
aws ec2 replace-route --route-table-id rtb-000000000 --destination-cidr-block 0.0.0.0/0 --nat-gateway-id "$O";
```

Comment: I very much appreciate yor help but i am getting a                                             
./test-script1.sh: line 3: $: command not found
./test-script1.sh: line 4: $: command not found

Comment: This is how my final command looks with your syntax and the proper id's inserted

Comment: @Matt slm edited my answer to confuse you, please review.

Comment: Thank you for your help but as I feared this wont work due to the fact that aws takes time to create the nat gateway thus editing the route table via a script is not immediately available so it fails. Will have to likely use a declarative program such as chef or ansible.

Comment: @Matt You can just wait in a loop, almost any language can accomplish almost any task.